# Why does android/gradle raise: "No resource identifier found for attribute 'compileSdkVersion'"?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a Android / Gradle based project

`AndroidManifest.xml` sets sdk:

```
...
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
          android:targetSdkVersion="22"
          android:compileSdkVersion="22"/>
...
```

In the Gradle configuration - build-extras.gradle I set sdk as well - roughly:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.myapp'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
...
```

When building the project with Gradle I get:

```
...
No resource identifier found for attribute 'compileSdkVersion' in package 'android'
...
```

Why ?

I got it to build removing `android:compileSdkVersion="22"` from the `AndroidManifest.xml` but that was a lucky punch after a lot of trial and errors. So I had liked to know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<uses-sdk>` has following syntax, and that does not include `compileSdkVersion` attribute:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

[uses-sdk element documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

`compileSdkVersion` is relevant for compilation process, not for execution of final application, therefore it has no place in application manifest.

Comment: nice explanation - shame on me not for inspecting the manifest file carefully enough must enable some android linting grrr.